# Statistics of Beta

Tags: support, beta-sites

Is there anyway I can get all statistics of all beta sites?

like:

- Unanswered questions
- Ratio of Answers
- No. of users

Comment: [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Couldn't I get as a list? By SQL or anything?

Comment: No, you'll have to write a scraper for this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thanks got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get those numbers from the [Stack Exchange sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Just pick out the beta sites; they are easily recognised by their site icon.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks, this is what I am searching for.